# Calculate field of view from a depth map

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, computer-vision, point-clouds

I have a depth numpy n*n array. In which the value of each cell represents the hight of that cell. I want to calculate the field of view. In other words:

```
if Pixel_height > viewer_height:
    pixels_behind = -1
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

[image: Green section in the pic]

edit: to be clear I want to create a position matrix similar to this green mask knowing we have a hight metrix n*m
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38I7y.jpg)

Comment: Please be a bit more specific. What exactly would you get as input? In addition to the height map and the viewer height, would you get something like a `(row, column)` pair indicating the position of the viewer? Or is the viewer always assumed to be at some point out of the height map?

Comment: From your description it should be as easy as `pixel_height[pixel_height > viewer_height] = -1`. However, as @jdehesa mentioned, maybe you can rephrase your question to be a bit mor precise. Maybe with a example array and expected output?

Comment: Also I'm not sure your logic is really right... If some pixel has height `a` and the viewer has height `h < a`, but the pixel immediately behind it has height `b > a`, then shouldn't that be visible too? That is, when you have a mountain in front of you, you can see up to its top, not just up to the point where it becomes taller than you.

Comment: Sorry you are right maybe its a bit not clear. Lets say the viewer is always in a fixed row and column. and yes the (row, column) represents position. and the viewer is always at same pose. what I want also get the projection behind those pixels. So if the front pixels are exceeding that limit, then the behind pixels value is also = -1

Comment: @user3885334 So does my suggestion solve your problem?

Comment: not really. Because as I am trying to say, Not only I want to annotate -1 to high pixels, but also to annotate -1 to the pixels behind it wrt to the point of view. So imagine you are a viewer, and there is the red box in front of you. So you cannot see behind it. I want to annotate -1 to the pixels behind that box wrt you.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this function, which is not really perfect but does something similar to what you say. It has a `resolution` parameter that represents how many "angle steps" in the circumference you want to consider. I'm not sure this is the "right" way to solve this problem though, and also I feel there should be a smarter way to do some of the operations, but anyway.

```py
import numpy as np

def view_field(height_map, viewer_height, viewer_pos, resolution=360):
    height_map = np.asarray(height_map)
    h, w = height_map.shape
    vi, vj = viewer_pos
    # Find locations higher than viewer
    m = height_map > viewer_height
    # Find angle of each pixel relative to viewer
    ii, jj = np.ogrid[-vi:h - vi, -vj:w - vj]
    a = np.arctan2(ii, jj)
    # Distance of each pixel to viewer
    d2 = np.square(ii) + np.square(jj)
    d = np.sqrt(d2)
    # Find angle range "behind" each pixel
    pix_size = 0.5
    ad = np.arccos(d / np.sqrt(d2 + np.square(pix_size)))
    # Minimum and maximum angle encompassed by each pixel
    amin = a - ad
    amax = a + ad
    # Define angle "bins"
    ar = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, resolution + 1)
    # Find the bin corresponding to each pixel
    b = np.digitize(a, ar) % resolution
    bmin = np.digitize(amin, ar) % resolution
    bmax = np.digitize(amax, ar) % resolution
    # Find the closest distance to a high pixel for each angle bin
    angdist = np.full_like(ar, np.inf)
    np.minimum.at(angdist, bmin[m], d[m])
    np.minimum.at(angdist, bmax[m], d[m])
    # Visibility is true if the pixel distance is less than the
    # visibility distance for its angle bin
    return d <= angdist[b]
```

Here is how it would go:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# A wavy function for testing
def ackley(x, y):
    return (-20 * np.exp(-0.2 * np.sqrt(0.5 * (np.square(x) + np.square(y))))
            - np.exp(0.5 * (np.cos(2 * np.pi * x) + np.cos(2 * np.pi * y)))
            + np.e + 20)

# Make input data
x, y = np.ogrid[-4:4:100j, -4:4:100j]
height_map = ackley(x, y)
viewer_height = 7.5
# Viewer coordinates are in "pixel space"
viewer_pos = (50, 70)
# Compute visibility
f = view_field(height_map, viewer_height, viewer_pos)
# Plot height map and result
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))
ax = plt.subplot(121, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(np.arange(100)[:, np.newaxis], np.arange(100),
                height_map, color='b', alpha=0.6)
ax.scatter3D(*viewer_pos, viewer_height, s=5, c='r', label='Viewer')
plt.title('Height map')
plt.legend()
plt.subplot(122)
plt.imshow(f)
plt.title('Visibility map')
plt.tight_layout()
```

And the resulting plot:

[image: Result plot]

Comment: I implemented it. Actually looks very good. I did set the pix_size to zero and it still appears to work very well. This way I am thinking, not converting the values to angles can increase accuracy.

Comment: @user3885334 I guess it depends on the resolution and the smoothness of your height map. A map with relatively high resolution and not too noisy shouldn't give much trouble. If it works fine for you setting `pix_size` to zero (which is reasonable, I thought of the whole `pix_size` / `amin` / `amax` thing before deciding for a binned solution, but it probably isn't that useful), you can obviously skip `ad` and only do `np.minimum.at(angdist, b[m], d[m])` to compute `angdist`. Feel free to post any other solution you can think of, either derived from this one or not.